# Buildroot with Qt support for a x86 platform

Tags: qt, buildroot, qtembedded

I am trying to build Buildroot with Qt support for a x86 platform this is what I get:

```
 Creating qmake. Please wait...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt-4.8.5/qmake'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt-4.8.5/qmake'

You have asked to use pkg-config and are cross-compiling.
Please make sure you have a correctly set-up pkg-config
environment!

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt-4.8.5/config.tests/unix/endian'
rm -f endiantest.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
rm -f endiantest 
rm -f Makefile
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt-4.8.5/config.tests/unix/endian'

The system floating point format could not be detected.
This may cause data to be generated in a wrong format
Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to see the final report.
./configure: 7688: ./configure: /home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/i686-buildroot-linux-uclibc-g++: not found
Error: QtScript was requested, but it can't be built on this platform.
make: *** [/home/userpc/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt-4.8.5/.stamp_configured] Error 1
```

I am using Buildroot toolchain and c++ support enabled. 
Target Architecture is i386 and Variant is i686.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message says it all:

```
.../buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/i686-buildroot-linux-uclibc-g++: not found
```

which says that the compiler cannot be found. This typically means that you have done some special things, like trying to build a package without having built the toolchain first, moving/removing generated files inside buildroot, ...

Starting from a clean directory should fix this (unless you made incorrect custom changes):

```
make clean
make
```

or in one go:

```
make clean all
```

If none of this solves your problem, I suggest to post your .config file and buildroot version on the buildroot mailing list.